# How to make Google Chrome JavaScript console persistent?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, debugging

Since I'm building a dynamic site, I need to track the changes between pages, ie. Ajax calls, POST, GET stuff and similar stuff.

I'm looking for the same functionality like in Firebug (where you can enable "persistent" and the console is not cleared every time you reload a page or submit a form.

So, my questions is: **is there a way to make Google Chrome JavaScript console persistent?**
(And if yes, how?)

**Update**: Copying the answer here, if anyone's still looking for this, Chrome 14+ has a setting in Developer Tools > Settings labelled "Console: Preserve log on navigation".

**Update 2**: the latest versions of Chrome (33+) have this option by right-clicking in the console.

**Update 3** (late 2017): The latest versions of Chrome (60+) have this option by opening the console, clicking the gear in the top right corner and selecting "preserve log"

Comment: its just "Preserve Log" now. I was being driven nuts and this post saved me a lot of time. thankyou lol

Comment: And now for the console logs it's "Preserve logs upon navigation"

Answer (score 499, accepted):

If anyone's still looking for this, I'm on Chrome 15.0.874.58 beta-m and I have a checkbox in *Developer Tools > Settings* labelled "Console: Preserve log on navigation". Does the job nicely.

[image: image of setting]

Comment: For anyone else that didn't no where Developer Tools > Settings are: when you've got the console open there's a cog in the bottom right of the screen, the "Preserve log upon navigation" is on the first tab in the Console section.

Comment: As of Chrome 17 right-clicking on console is providing access on that option either.

Comment: As of 2019, for settings you click the three little vertically stacked dots in the far right on the Dev Tools menu bar :-)

Comment: As of Chrome v110.0.5481.77 the option is  `Preserve log` on the `Console` tab of `DevTools` (F12). You can locate it in the first column, the second row. Edit: look the @Simon 's reply

Comment: it preserves logs on refresh but it doesn't preserve its reponses. Any solution to that?

Comment: Are you referring to the Network tab, @mudassar-malik? There's a 'preserve log' checkbox at the top of that too.

Comment: yes it has a preserve logs tab but my point is that when i refresh my page it does not preserve ajax call responses. However the logs are still presistant.

Comment: Important: You *must* also have "Selected context only" **unchecked** or else this setting does nothing!

Answer (score 71):

[image]

at Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Important: You *must* also have "Selected context only" **unchecked** or else this setting does nothing!

Answer (score 13):

As of Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit):

1. Click the ellipsis in top right of Developer Tools [image: top ellipsis]
2. Navigate to `Settings > Preferences > Console`
3. Check `Preserve log upon navigation`

[image: console options]

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't support that functionality yet, although there was talk in December 2010 about adding in the next major release...

*This answer is no longer valid*

Comment: I suspected this. It's the reason why I have to keep 
Firefox around. Even FireBug Lite doesn't have persistent console.

Comment: I'll have to learn how it was done in FireBug and make my first google-chrome extension :)

Comment: That would be great if you do - keep me posted!

Comment: Turned out I didn't need it bad anough :/

Comment: Chrome provides this functionality

Comment: @uneakharsh please do not downvote for that. Look at when the answer was written (March 2011). The functionality has been added since this answer was posted...

Comment: @BenM I am not un-downvote it, it says its locked, also your reply was misleading, if its anyway possible then please delete your answer.

Comment: @uneakharsh Upvoting because this was the correct answer when it was written (Mar 2011). You don't delete answers, period.

Comment: @BenM "You don't delete answers." and who is the arbitrator to the rule? Ofcourse you delete answers when they are wrong. Do I have to be more obvious?

Comment: Wrong answers can be useful.

Comment: @uneakharsh I didn't say that. It was José Luis!

Answer (score 3):

Try this to enable console on popups

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome v102

1. I opened Chrome Dev Tools,
2. I clicked on "gear" icon (Top right corner)
3. Enable "Preserve log" checkbox

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the "preserve logs" options enabled and still had the Console losing focus to the Sources tab. If that happens (apparently during debugging), it helps to disable "Focus sources panel when triggering a breakpoint" in "Settings > Preferences > Sources".

Comment: Losing focus is a different issue but thanks for making it known.