# Stop the console log clearing when you click a link in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Referred to as the "JavaScript console", when you click on a link, the log is cleared.

Is there a way to stop this log from being cleared when you click on a link?

The problem is that an event triggered onClick is returning an error which makes it harder to diagnose because the error is only displayed for a short time before being cleared.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the answer: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89965

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Google Chrome JavaScript console persistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327955/how-to-make-google-chrome-javascript-console-persistent)

Answer (score 59):

This is an option in the developer tools. Right click the console, and select **Preserve Log upon Navigation**, or go through the settings menu (bottom right cog-looking icon in the devtools).

[image: pic]

Comment: Right click where on the console? When I right click in most places on the console I just see: "Inspect element". I could not see a cog in the bottom right under "chrome://settings/browser". Are you sure this is Google Chrome?

Comment: You need to open the developer tools with Ctrl + Alt (or Cmd + Option) + I.

Comment: As of Chrome 70 (and maybe before that) the settings cog is at the top right of the console window. Click it, and then click 'Preserve log'.

Answer (score 44):

Google Chrome Version: **65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
Under the *Network* tab check **Preserve Log**

[image]

Google Chrome:*Version **39.0.2171.95** (64-bit)*
Console -> Settings -> Preserver log
[image]

Comment: This has now moved. Press the blue cogwheel at the top right of the Console, then tick Preserve log.

Comment: The option is there in Chrome 109, but it no longer works. I remember it used to.

Comment: It still works. I had to: click 'Default levels', add 'Verbose' so it changes to 'All levels'; click 'Preserve log' and 'Log XMLHttpRequests'; and unclick 'Selected context only'. I also unclicked 'Group similar messages in console' so it displays in order of event.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: That cog does not exist on my version: "Google Chrome is up to date (13.0.82.112)".

What version are you using?

Comment: Chromium 15.0.846.0 (Developer Build 95631). http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/