# jQuery doesn't work without alert

Tags: jquery

I have some JavaScript below, but it doesn't work unless I have the `alert` as shown below. I know this is some sort of timing issue, but I have no idea how to go about fixing it. Any thoughts?

```
$(function() {
    $("#search_field").tokenInput("/searches/suggest_gems.json", {
    onAdd: function (item) {
    $('#search_field').val(item.name);
    // Doesn't work without alert("hi");
    },
    crossDomain: false,
    tokenLimit: 1,
    tokenValue: name
    });
});
```

Comment: What does this mean?  "Does not work without alert"?  What is this supposed to do?  What are your errors?  What exactly are we fixing?

Comment: You might want to set an interval with `setInterval()` or use `setTimeout()` (look for those on Google, they might help you out) !

Comment: Yes it does, it's just that the `alert()` pauses things long enough for something else to catch up behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues before. What I've found to work is using `$(window).load(function(){...})` instead of `$(function(){...})`. This buys enough time to let anything that's not ready by the time the DOM is loaded to be ready by the time the window is loaded fully. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try checking the console for errors. In Chrome you can make the console persistent :https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661797/1446608

Sounds like an async problem. When you are using the `alert`, code execution stops, and the error does not show. If you are not using the alert, an error stops code executions, so *onAdd* is never fired, so that code won't be executed.

To start, try checking if the element *#search_field* still exists in the DOM when *onAdd* is fired.

Check also that item.*name* is not undefined.

Check what happens before *onAdd* is fired.