# Want to POST data to a website using cURL But their are no POST_FIELDS Seen

Tags: javascript, curl

Hiii guys,

I pretty well know how to program in php/curl and use the available options.

I wanted to know that if we want to POST data to a website ( In my case i have to answer a question in a website by clicking a link which is essentially javascript ) 
But the LIVEhttpHeaders addon which i use does not provide an post data.
That is,
The addon shows me the following when i click the required link

```
http://www.xyz.com/ans.do?q=X2&id=cX&cid=1&oid=5
POST /ans.do?q=X2&id=cX&cid=1&oid=5 HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://www.xyz.com/Quiz.do?qId=291241
Cookie: __utma=1.399093274.1364213174.1365000359.1365004345.14;
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 5876
Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2013 15:59:02 GMT
```

I have created a curl script and have reached till the quiz.. and can parse the requires arguments ( q,id,cid,oid etc ).
But how do i actually post data  ( Click the option ) since their is no POST_FIELD???

I have used the following code till now

```
$url_c="$ser/ans.do?q=$q&id=$id&cid=$cid&oid=$oid;
$url_p="$ser/Quiz.do?qId=$qid";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_c);   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: */*")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip,deflate");       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_p);  
$html=curl_exec($ch);
```

But the option remains as such.
Tried with making POST as 1 , FOLLOWLOCATION , but dint work.

Can i have help in this???

Comment: So they are not posting any data, looks like they are sending all of the details in the querystring.

Comment: @epascarello yup true... they are using query string...

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST, true` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array)`.  Did you set POSTFIELDS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using live http headers why dont you use chrome developer tools and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327955/how-to-make-google-chrome-javascript-console-persistent) to make the console persistent and get the post params.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... i still dint get the post fields..Chrome is just like firebug addon which i also used for this problem..any other suggestion??

Comment: Did you make it persistent using the link I gave ? If yes, then it should have logged the POST request in the network tab and you can easily see the params.

Comment: Yes i did what you told...i got all the .css and .js file along with the same query string as above... what has to be done next???

Comment: When you click submit on the quiz do you see anything new in the Network tab ? that should be your POST request which you are looking for

Comment: Yeah i got a new string in networks tab..i copied it as curl..and got this!!curl "http://www.xyz.com/ans.do?q=Xee&id=3443&cid=1&oid=2" -X POST -H "Origin: http://www.xyz.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "Host: www.xyz.com" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.12 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://www.xyz.com/Quiz.do?qId=291241" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=70C5774AF6D906976BAC954C7619704F; city=-; region=-; id=3add2560-0e07-4c69-b7f9-f829bc47ad21;WHICH IS SAME

Comment: THIS IS SAME AS THE CODE GENERATED BY LIVEHTTPHEADERS..!

Comment: Thanx but w3schools may have post data...not mine:) thx for the help but stil m stuck ther

Comment: if yours doesnt then they are using query params instead of post fields. Why dont you post without any post body and with query params to see the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url_c="$ser/ans.do;
$query = q=$q&id=$id&cid=$cid&oid=$oid;
$url_p="$ser/Quiz.do?qId=$qid";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_c);   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: *")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip,deflate");       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_p);
```

Did you set these?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

$html=curl_exec($ch);
```