# ionic3 native paypal init error

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3

I am doing an integration between my ionic3 app and Paypal, I am following the doc from official ionic native paypal plugin website. But when I press the button to trigger the paypal, it refresh to the root page of the app.

Here is my code:

```
gotoPaypal(){
this.pppayment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
this.payPal.init({
    PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'dgdfghfjfhgjghjadsasfdsdfsghkgjkjhk',
    PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'hasvahgsdvajbdhgvcasdh sahgdvasdvagksd'
  }).then(() => {
  this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
  })).then(() => {
    this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(this.pppayment).then(() => {
    }, () => {
          console.log("Paypal 3333");
    });
  }, () => {
  console.log("Paypal 2222");      
  });
}, () => {
  console.log("Paypal 1111");
});
}
```

And before it's auto refresh, I see console printed "Paypal 1111", so I think init Paypal have error, Anyone know what happen or how to fix?

Comment: you can print the error and see... `(err) => {
  console.log(err);
}`

Comment: when I trigger gotoPaypal(), the app will refresh to the root page, so I don't have enough time to see the log...

Comment: you have an option to persist the log in dev tools of browser

Comment: How can I do that, thanks a lot

Comment: chrome? in console section there should be a checkbox

Comment: Network tab -> preserve log

Comment: @SurajRao no checkbox in console section

Comment: @ManelAlonso, yes I have checked, but console still refresh when the page refresh

Comment: @Nulra click on the settings icon in console section

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327955/how-to-make-google-chrome-javascript-console-persistent

Comment: 3 dots -> Settings -> Console -> Preserve log upon navigation

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SurajRao I have the log now

Comment: Thanks @ManelAlonso