# Is the unload event triggered when the page is reloaded by the location.reload() method?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is the [unload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) triggered when the page is reloaded by the [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method?

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    console.log('unload event was triggered');
});
```

```js
location.reload();  // reload the current URL
```

Comment: You can use `beforeunload` event instead `unload`

Comment: I'm seeing an issue where unload isn't triggered in this case. Is this what you found too? What browser btw

Comment: @pushkin When I have tested `location.reload()` after adding an event listener for `unload` event, I found that the `unload` event was triggered in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari browser. I have tested in the web consoles of each browser with ["preserve log" option turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977830/8581025).