# Page refreshing when registering new user in firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication, page-refresh

I am developing a firebase website, and when I try to register an account, the page refreshes. The function is called in the onsubmit method of a form.

```html
<form id="register_form" onsubmit="registerNewUser(); return false;">
```

I put return false, but it keeps on refreshing the page. I did more debugging, and found out it is not when the form is submitted, but rather when creating the new user. Here is my user registration code.

```js
function registerNewUser() {  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($("#register_email").val, $("#register_password").val)
    .then((user) => {
      // Signed in 
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      window.alert(errorMessage);
      // ..
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the console (before it refreshes)? You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661797/863110) to keep the logs after navigation.

Comment: Could you try using `e.preventDefault()` and let us know what happens then?

Comment: @yifansong I tried event.preventDefault(); It kept the page from refresh, but it doesn't create a new account.

Comment: @yifansong also now its saying there was a databreach on my site. I was using 000webhost for testing. Is this also important?

Comment: Really can't tell what your issue is, perhaps you can tinker around some more with `e.preventDefault()`, work out some sort of snippet where you've isolated the bits specific to your question. So far, to me, it sounds like you might be cutting off part of your code that is causing the issue, try to create a snippet that shows your code not working. As for the databreach, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

The reload happens because you try registering the same user more than once. Try changing the user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).