# matching form input with JSON file [SOLVED ✔ ]

Tags: javascript, html

I need help. I created a login form using a JSON file for a storage account.
The case is when the user enters a username & password, it will be validated into the JSON file. If they match, it will continue to index.html. If it's wrong, a warning will appear.
I use it for loops because the data in the JSON file is an array. So I think looping is the right choice. But I can't use the event.preventDefault().

JSON file:

```
{ "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "username": "john20",
        "password": "doe20"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Julia",
        "last_name": "Chan",
        "email": "juliachan@gmail.com",
        "username": "julia19",
        "password": "chan19"
    }
    ]
}
```

and the HTML, CSS, javascript is:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://lambert18.github.io/onbena/accounts.json";

ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json");

ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200) {
        var jcontent = JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);
        var i;

        document.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
        function validateForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            let uName = document.getElementById("username").value;
            let pWord = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var getU;

            for(getU = 0; getU < jcontent.users.length; getU++) {
            if(uName !== jcontent.users.username && pWord !== jcontent.users.password) {
                alert("Username or Password is wrong!");
            }
            else if(uName === jcontent.users.username && pWord === jcontent.users.password) {
                alert("Successfully login!")
                // window.location.href = '../index.html';
            }
          }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < jcontent.users.length; i++) {
            output.innerHTML = jcontent.users[i].first_name + ' ' + jcontent.users[i].last_name;
            console.log(jcontent.users[i].first_name + ' ' + jcontent.users[i].last_name);
        }

        console.log(jcontent);
        console.log(jcontent.users[0].first_name);
    }
}



ajaxhttp.send(null);

output.innerHTML = "nothing";
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

center {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 340px; padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  a:hover {
  color: #4FDA8C; }

input { font: 16px/26px "Raleway", sans-serif; }

body {
  background-color: #f1f2f2;
  font: 16px/26px "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: white;
  color: black;}

.form-wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #BEBEBE;
}

.form-wrap .tabs { overflow: hidden; }

.form-wrap .tabs h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.form-wrap .tabs h3 a {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #e6e7e8;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
}

.form-wrap .tabs h3 a.active { background-color: #fff; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content { padding: 1.5em; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content div[id$="tab-content"] { display: none; }

.form-wrap .tabs-content .active { display: block !important; }

.form-wrap form .input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: .8em 0 10px .8em;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 .8em 0;
  padding-right: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-wrap form .button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .8em 0 10px .8em;
  background-color: #28A55F;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.form-wrap form .button:hover { background-color: #4FDA8C; }

.form-wrap form .checkbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: .5em 0 1.5em;
}

.form-wrap form .checkbox:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-wrap form label[for] {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-wrap form label[for]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -14px;
}

.form-wrap form label[for]:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: -10px;
    border: 3px solid #28A55F;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.form-wrap .help-text { margin-top: .6em; }

.form-wrap .help-text p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.text-logo {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Archivo", sans-serif!important;
  color: var(--black)!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Custom StyleSheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/form-login.css" />

        <title>Onbena Shop</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="text-logo">ONBENA SHOP</h1>
            <h2><b>Login</b></h2>
            <p>You need to login before access it</p>
            <form  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" id="username">
                    <span id="help-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                    <span id="help-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                    <a href="./" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
                </div>
                <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.html">Sign up now</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="js/forms.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`  it is replaced by `document.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);`

Comment: Any errors in the console? (Use [preserve log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661797/863110)) to prevent the console to clear upon navigation (after the form submitted)

Comment: @MisterJojo I've removed it, but for the array number account (2) named Julia Chan doesn't match, but for john (1) it does.

Comment: yes, because your `addEventListener("submit"` is inside your ajax call...

Comment: @MoshFeu there had been an error, but @MisterJojo tell me to remove the `onsubmit` on the form. After that, there are no errors, but the data is only read in the first array.

Comment: Ok. Now try to add `e.preventDefault()` in the next line of `function validateForm(e) {`

Comment: @MisterJojo What should I do? move `addeventListener` outside the ajax call? I've done it, but the `validateForm()` function isn't used

Comment: @MoshFeu Ok, data can be read in the array (2). But now the problem is looping.
I just entered the username & password with the same data in the array (2). But the result is 2 alerts. "Username or Password is wrong!", after that "Successfully login!"

Comment: I already update the script on javascript.

Comment: Don't use `for` loop. Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). If the result is `undefined`, the login details are wrong. If it's not, you have the user.

Comment: Hi @MoshFeu I try to use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and it's working! no duplicate alerts again. Thank you!

Comment: Sure :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
latest update

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "./data/accounts.json";

ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json");
ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200) {
        var jcontent = JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);
        var i;
        document.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
        function validateForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            let uName = document.getElementById("username").value;
            let pWord = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if(jcontent.users.find(r => r.username == uName && r.password == pWord)) {
                alert("Successfully login!")
                // window.location.href = '../index.html';
            }
            else {
                alert("Username or Password is wrong!");
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < jcontent.users.length; i++) {
            output.innerHTML = jcontent.users[i].first_name + ' ' + jcontent.users[i].last_name;
            // output2.innerHTML = jcontent.users[i].first_name + ' ' + jcontent.users[i].last_name;
            console.log(jcontent.users[i].first_name + ' ' + jcontent.users[i].last_name);
        }


        console.log(jcontent);
        console.log(jcontent.users[0].first_name);
    }
}

ajaxhttp.send(null);
output.innerHTML = "nothing";
```