# Response data isn't even showing in console. I have tried everything. But not getting a proper solution for that

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks

I am sending request from react to django to know if we've this user or not. django is sending response back but it's not even showing in console in react.

here is my React Code:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/writer-login/'

function TeacherLogin() {
    const[writerLoginData, setWriterLoginData] = useState({
        'writer_email' : '',
        'writer_password': ''
        });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
    setWriterLoginData({
        ...writerLoginData,
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
    }

    const submitForm = () => {
        const writerLoginFormData = new FormData();
        writerLoginFormData.append('writer_email',writerLoginData.writer_email)
        writerLoginFormData.append('writer_password',writerLoginData.writer_password)

        try {
            axios.post(BASE_URL,writerLoginFormData).then((res) => { 
                console.log('Found')
                console.log(res.data)
                if(res.data === true) {
                    localStorage.setItem('writerLoginStatus',true)
                    window.Location.href="/writer-dashboard";
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
    const writerLoginStatus = localStorage.getItem('writerLoginStatus')
    if(writerLoginStatus === 'true'){
        window.Location.href="/writer-dashboard";
    }
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            
                            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={writerLoginData.writer_name} onChange={handleChange} name ="writer_email"  type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={writerLoginData.writer_password} onChange={handleChange} name ="writer_password"  type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        
                        <Button onClick={submitForm} variant="success me-5" type="submit">Login
                        </Button>
    );
}

export default TeacherLogin;
```

here is my django code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def WriterLoginDetails(request):
    writer_email = request.POST['writer_email']
    writer_password = request.POST['writer_password']
    writerData = models.Writer.objects.get(writer_email = writer_email, writer_password = writer_password)
    if writerData:
        print('data found')
        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
    else: 
        print('no data found')
        return JsonResponse({'bool':False})
```

I have tried to console it in browser and even in network but I am not getting anything

Comment: Can you change the onchange of button as follows
onClick={()=>submitForm()}

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but when the axios.post() promise is rejected, you should add a .catch() callback instead of wrapping your post call in a try catch. (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-promise-methods/)

The try except blocks only catch error that occur when calling axios.post(), but no errors that occur when resolving the promise.

Comment: Which Form library are you using?

Comment: So if you `console.log(res)` to see the whole response, what do you get?

Comment: @michjnich showing data in console for like half second

Comment: @AjayGhosh if i will use onClick. i wont be able to use value parameter. i think and i am using react bootstrap. just deleted my form code to short the code here

Comment: window.Location.href="/writter-dashboard";
 Can you comment this and check if the response is proper seen in console

Comment: or tick the preserve logs option in above the console
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977830/9586519

Comment: @AjayGhosh it's showing this data in console now {bool: true}

Comment: Now you can do what ever you want to do